# H2 equivalent to Oracle's new_time function

Tags: oracle, function, h2

Does anybody know how to implement Oracle's [new_time](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions092.htm) function in an H2 database? I've been searching and don't see anything about how to convert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a [user defined function](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions).

Comment: I did end up adding a user defined function. 

I was more asking about the logic within the UDF to comparable to the Oracle function. Thanks for the suggestion and link.

Comment: I had a look at how to write the `NEW_TIME` function in Java, but so far I was not able to get it working... it is complicated. Maybe it is easier when using JodaTime, not sure.

Comment: I thought it might be. It's definitely beyond my skill set at this point. Thanks for the comment Thomas!

Answer (score 1):

Creating stored procedures in H2 is so easy, just create an static method and that's all. So just implement your required function as an static method, compile your code, have it in the classpath (your applications' or H2's).